# Why is my reactstrap modal not opening when my button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, reactstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am working on a React app, trying to use the reactstrap library to open a modal when a button is clicked. This modal will have a form with 2 fields, First Name and Last Name. When the form is submitted 2 cells in a table on the main page should be updated with the First Name and Last Name values.

I would like some help with 2 issues in my current code:

1. I can't get the modal to pop up when the button is clicked.
2. I can't figure out how to populate the table cells with the data from the modal form.

Here is my current code for the ModalLeads file, which contains the modal:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  ModalHeader,
  Button,
  Col,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Label
} from "reactstrap";

class ModalLeads extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      info: false,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,

    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  //******************************************************************** */
  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.state.info}
        toggle={this.toggleInfo}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
        className={"modal-lg " + this.props.className}
      >
        <Form
          action=""
          method="POST"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSubmit={this.onCreate}
          encType="multipart/form-data"
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleInfo} className="blue-header">
            <i className="cui-people"></i>Leads
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <FormGroup row className="my-0">

              <Col xs="8">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</Label>
                  <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="firstName"
                    type="text"
                    id="firstName"
                    value={this.state.firstName || ""}
                    placeholder="Enter First Name"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col xs="4">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</Label>
                  <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="lastName"
                    type="text"
                    id="lastName"
                    value={this.state.lastName || ""}
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.toggleInfo}>
              <i className="cis-check-double-alt"></i> Save
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="secondary"
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggleInfo();
                this.resetForm();
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalLeads;
```

And here is my current code for the Leads file, which includes a ModalLeads element:

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from "react-bootstrap-table";
import "react-bootstrap-table/dist//react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css";
import LeadsModal from "../Modal/ModalLeads";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  Row,
  ModalFooter
} from "reactstrap";

// state value for info is initially set to false but should be updated to true when we want to trigger the modal to show:

class Leads extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      modalClient: false,
      leadId: null,
      info: false,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
}
this.toggleInfo = this.toggleInfo.bind(this);

}

toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }


// function to change the state value for info, should run when we want to open or close the modal:

  toggleInfo(leadId) {
    this.setState({
      info: !this.state.info
    });

  }
buttonFormat(cell, row) {
    //const id = api + `clients/${row.id}`;
    const id = row.id;
    return (
      <Row>
        <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.toggleInfo(id)}>
          <i className="cis-comment-bubble-edit"></i>
        </Button>

      </Row>
    );
  }

render() {
    return (


          {/************************ Windows Modal */}

          <LeadsModal
            isOpen={this.state.info}
            toggle={this.toggleInfo}
            backdrop="static"
            keyboard={false}
            className={"modal-lg " + this.props.className}
          />

// I use react-bootstrap-table for rendering the grid:

<div>
 <Card>
 <CardBody>


 <CardBody>
            <BootstrapTable
              data={this.state.table}
              version="4"
              striped
              hover
              pagination
              options={this.options}
            >
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="firstName" dataSort>
                First Name
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="lastName" dataSort>
                Last Name
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField="email">
                Email
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="phone" dataSort>
                Phone
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort>
                Title
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn
                dataField="id"
                dataFormat={this.buttonFormat.bind(this)}
              >
                Action
              </TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Leads;
```

Comment: sorry for not clean, yes I want to open to modal from onClick and I need to send the state value for fill the input

Comment: my problem how I fill my input with the state

Comment: I just updated your question and code to be more clear. In the future, please try to be as clear as possible when describing your issue, giving as much detail as you can. Also, please do not separate code for the same file into multiple snippets as it makes the code much more difficult to read and copy when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of general notes:

1. I would not recommend combining reactstrap with react-bootstrap. They are two different libraries that serve pretty much the same purpose, but they are structured differently and cannot be counted on to play nicely together. Instead, you should use tables, buttons, modals, etc. all from one or the other. But for the purposes of this answer, I have kept both libraries as you have them.
2. It's not clear to me how you are planning on populating the table with rows, so I am going to hard-code a few in my example.

And a few of the issues in your code:

1. The code you shared is not actually compiling. The `<CardBody>` tag is repeated twice in the Leads file but only closed once, and the `<LeadsModal>` element is outside the root `<div>`.
2. You have both a function and a variable named `toggleInfo`, which was confusing the code when it tried to pass in the function to the `ModalLeads` component. Renaming one fixes that issue.
3. You weren't passing in enough data to `ModalLeads` as `props`, and also were not saving everything you needed to be saving in its `state`.
4. You don't need both a form `onSubmit` and a submit button `onClick`. The form's `onSubmit` function will run when the submit button is clicked.

Here is my working example, which I believe satisfies everything you were asking about:

ModalLeads file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  ModalHeader,
  Button,
  Col,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Label
} from "reactstrap";

class ModalLeads extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalClient: false,
      info: this.props.isOpen,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateRowBound(
      this.props.leadId,
      this.state.firstName,
      this.state.lastName
    );
    this.props.toggleInfoBound();
    this.resetForm();
  };

  resetForm() {
    this.state.firstName = null;
    this.state.lastName = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
        toggle={() => {
          this.props.toggleInfoBound();
          this.resetForm();
        }}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
        className={"modal-lg " + this.props.className}
      >
        <Form
          id="name-change-form"
          action=""
          method="POST"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          encType="multipart/form-data"
        >
          <ModalHeader
            toggle={() => {
              this.props.toggleInfoBound();
              this.resetForm();
            }}
            className="blue-header"
          >
            <i className="cui-people"></i>Leads
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <FormGroup row className="my-0">
              <Col xs="8">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</Label>
                  <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="firstName"
                    type="text"
                    id="firstName"
                    value={this.state.firstName || ""}
                    placeholder="Enter First Name"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col xs="4">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</Label>
                  <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="lastName"
                    type="text"
                    id="lastName"
                    value={this.state.lastName || ""}
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" type="submit">
              <i className="cis-check-double-alt"></i> Save
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="secondary"
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.toggleInfoBound();
                this.resetForm();
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalLeads;
```

Leads file:

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from "react-bootstrap-table";
import "react-bootstrap-table/dist//react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css";
import LeadsModal from "../Modal/ModalLeads";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  Row,
  ModalFooter
} from "reactstrap";

class Leads extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalClient: false,
      leadId: null,
      info: false,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      table: [
        {
          firstName: "Elvis",
          lastName: "Presley",
          email: "elvis@example.com",
          phone: "(123) 456-7890",
          title: "King",
          id: "0"
        },
        {
          firstName: "Paul",
          lastName: "McCartney",
          email: "paul@example.com",
          phone: "(987) 654-3210",
          title: "Beatle",
          id: "1"
        },
        {
          firstName: "Mick",
          lastName: "Jagger",
          email: "mick@example.com",
          phone: "(800) 867-5309",
          title: "Stone",
          id: "2"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.toggleInfoBound = this.toggleInfo.bind(this);
    this.updateRowBound = this.updateRow.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

  toggleInfo(leadId) {
    this.state.leadId = leadId;
    this.setState({
      info: !this.state.info
    });
  }

  buttonFormat(cell, row) {
    const id = row.id;
    return (
      <Row>
        <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.toggleInfo(id)}>
          <i className="cis-comment-bubble-edit"></i>Change Name
        </Button>
      </Row>
    );
  }

  updateRow(leadId, firstName, lastName) {
    var rowToUpdate = this.state.table.find(x => x.id === leadId);
    rowToUpdate.firstName = firstName;
    rowToUpdate.lastName = lastName;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LeadsModal
          isOpen={this.state.info}
          toggleInfoBound={this.toggleInfoBound}
          updateRowBound={this.updateRowBound}
          backdrop="static"
          keyboard={false}
          className={"modal-lg " + this.props.className}
          leadId={this.state.leadId}
        />
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <BootstrapTable
              data={this.state.table}
              version="4"
              striped
              hover
              pagination
              options={this.options}
            >
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="firstName" dataSort>
                First Name
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="lastName" dataSort>
                Last Name
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField="email">
                Email
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="phone" dataSort>
                Phone
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort>
                Title
              </TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn
                dataField="id"
                dataFormat={this.buttonFormat.bind(this)}
              >
                Action
              </TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Leads;
```

Comment: Hey sfabota, I need the pas state for I can fill the form or me researcher  on the modal, I did like this
```
<LeadsModal
            isOpen={this.state.info}
            toggleInfoBound={this.toggleInfoBound}
            backdrop="static"
            keyboard={false}
            leadId={this.state.leadId}
            firstName={this.state.firstName}
            lastName={this.state.lastName}
/>
```

this  how I get the values and fill the form

Comment: How I can get the props in modal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first comment. Is something in the code I provided not working for you? Regarding how to get the props in the modal, just use `this.props.isOpen`, `this.props.leadId`, etc.

Comment: Or if you were asking how to pass props to the modal, it's just like you did in your first comment.